# MSACCESS, how to edit a record after insert using the "after insert" trigger

Tags: ms-access

MS Office 365 ProPlus, Access 2007 - 2016

I'm trying/failing to change the value of a field in a table after it is inserted using the "after insert" trigger.  Something like this...

```
EditRecord
    SetField
        Name orig_id
        Value = [mytable].[id]
End EditRecord
```

This doesn't seem to work.
USysApplicationLog gives...

```
SourceObject = mytable.AfterInsert
DataMacro InstanceID = {489D5697-5247-44A8-AE3C-3773A25F72E5}
Error Number = -20335
Category = Execution
Object Type = Macro
Description = EditRecord failed because the default alias represents a record which is read only.
```

The field is not read only.  After the fact I can edit it just fine. I don't know what the "default alias" is nor what that even means.

If the trigger can't do this, can you think of another way to accomplish the same thing ?

Comment: I have never used Data Macros. I don't use any macros at all. Why would you need to change an ID value?

Comment: I tried to replicate this. DataMacro does not error - doesn't do anything, field value is not changed. Why would you reference [mytable] as source of a value?

Comment: The actual filed is a date field used to identify when a task is expected to finish (call it "expected_finish").  Customers can change that value, but they also want to know what it was initially before any changes.  So I added a column called "initial_expected_finish".  Setting that value when the record was initially inserted made sense to me.  I suppose I could require the users to enter the value and then have a before update trigger reject everything except identical entries, but they won't like that.

Comment: initial_expected_finish could be set by DefaultValue property then textbox on form can be locked so it cannot be edited, just viewed.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to use the AfterInsert, since then the record is already saved, and tucked away nicely, and everything you need to change in that record is assumed to have been done. In fact, the default context will cause the record in question to be read only. You CAN get around this by pulling the record again, (looking up a record), but if you modify it again then all of the triggers for that record will fire again.

So I ONLY suggest you use this event to sum() or add/edit OTHER tables, but not the record that was just edited and saved.

If you need/want to update this current record, then move your "edit" or "modify" code to the "BeforeChange". This event not only lets you edit/modify right before the save (and thus preventing endless loops in which the update triggers fire again and again), but the CURRENT record is in full context, and you don't even need any "edit record" command, since you have the fresh un-saved record right in context. You thus can use SetField without the need for EditRecord.

So, the AfterInsert is really too late here, and if you could modify the record in that event, you will cause the AfteUpdate event to fire again if you do use a workaround.

Now, if you use BeforeChange, it will fire for both insert and edits (change). So, if your code really only needs to run when inserting, you can check this status by using

```
If [isinsert] = True then
```

## Edit

Also, it looks like your code is attempting to save (capture) the previous value, and if it is, then you can use:

```
[old].[id]
```

Of course this does not make too much sense for "id", since that is usually an autonumber PK column, but for grabbing other values during an update in the BeforeChange event, you can certainly test + inspect the previous (old) values.

Comment: It's not really an id field, it's a date which reflects an initial time estimate before users move the date goal posts.  ( I probably should have said that earlier, sorry).  I tried the "if [IsInsert] = True " in the update trigger and that worked.  Thanks, and I clicked the up-arrow on your post for that.  Who'd have thunk that an insert triggers an update ?

Comment: Thanks. And yes, the before change will run if you change, or add a new record. It simple some code that runs when you update, and a insert does suggest a add recod, and then you modify that added record. If you keeping a running total on some say part number, then you need to know if this is a insert, but you likely keep a common code in the change event. (and yes, id was just a example to get old, and ID is a bad example on my part.

Comment: Syntax for viewing a data control's old value is: `controlname.OldValue`. What is `[isinsert]`?

Comment: Isinsert let's your code check if this is a new record or you are changing (we are in the change event) - so it's going to fire for both events

Comment: Still not clear to me what [isinsert] is - variable, function, property, field?

Comment: It is a built in system variable that is = true if the record you are dealing with in the before change event is a new record, or simply that the record you are modifying is the result of a insert as opposed to a update of a existing record. Since the before change event fires in both cases then your code can still check this built in flag, and thus you can have code only run if the record is a new record. (or have code only run if it is a existing record that is being modified).

Comment: The way to think of this setting is just like in any forms event code, you can go if me.NewRecord = True then do something. So in forms event code, you can use me.NewRecord (again a built in Boolean system flag that you can use). It thus turns out, you have a number of such flags and pre-built settings in data triggers also for your use.